# How to add a Reply To: header to mail when using postfix and Mailgun as SMTP server?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I'm trying to add a Reply To: header to mail when using postfix on Ubuntu 19 and SMTP for mailing via Mailgun.

Mail works fine when testing with `swak`, but mail to my final destination `@protonmail.com` has the return address of `postmaster@mail.mailgunexampledomain.com` .

I've followed this Q/A [linux - Adding reply-to header for simple postfix mailing list - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248107/adding-reply-to-header-for-simple-postfix-mailing-list) and the answer by `tarleb`, which says:

```
The Reply-To header can be added using the smtp_header_checks option:

smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks.pcre

where header_checks.pcre contains something like

/^To: your-mailing-list@example.net/  PREPEND Reply-To: <your-mailing-list@example.net>
```

Two issues: One is the warning I get when I run `postmap header_checks.pcre` to get `postfix` to use the file:

```
header_checks.pcre, line 1: record is in "key: value" format; is this an alias file?
```

The second issue - that probably is a result of the first issue - is that the Reply To: header isn't added to mail.

---

**Edit 1/09/20:**

`Hagan's` string

```
/^From:[[:space:]]your-mailing-list@example.net/ PREPEND Reply-To:your-mailing-list@example.net
```

fixes the `header_checks.pcre` error, but a Reply To: header is still not added to emails. No other postfix or mail related errors in server logs.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
/^From:[[:space:]]your-mailing-list@example.net/ PREPEND Reply-To:your-mailing-list@example.net
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the "alias file" warning I get; but still no Reply To: field, even with the email addresses bracketed with < and > like my example.